How to keep anchorNode unchanged when using setStart function of Range
Use the anchorNode of Selection to check the starting node,
Using setStart on range to change the range, the anchorNode will change.
[mouse drag & drop]

[Run range.setStart(p, 1)]

Is it possible to capture an area so that the standard anchornode does not change?
I looked for it in MDN Web Docs,
but I couldn't find a way to use AnchorNode because it said a change event is performed when an area is selected.
